# Left join not working - not talking about my bones

Tags: join, query

I have two tables

dbo.eletter:

- eletter_id
- eletter_title
- eletter_body
- eletter_form
- eletter_teacherID
- eletter_signed
- eletter_parentID

dbo.status:

- status_id
- status_letterid
- status_parentid
- status_status

And the following query:

```
SELECT eletter_id, eletter_form, status_letterid, status_parentid
FROM dbo.eletter T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.status T2 ON T2.status_letterid = T1.eletter_id
```

The above gives me

```
|------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------|
| eletter_id | eletter_form | status_letterid | status_parentid |
|------------+_-------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    1       |    Year 5    |     1           |     3           |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    2       |    Year 7    |                 |                 |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    3       |    Year 8    |                 |                 |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    4       |    Year 6    |                 |                 |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    5       |    Year 5    |     5           |     1           |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    1       |    Year 5    |     6           |     3           |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
```

the output i would like to have is 
all the letters for parentid 3 for the year 5

```
|------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------|
| eletter_id | eletter_form | status_letterid | status_parentid |
|------------+_-------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    1       |    Year 5    |     1           |     3           |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    2       |    Year 7    |                 |                 |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    3       |    Year 8    |                 |                 |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    4       |    Year 6    |                 |                 |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    5       |    Year 5    |     5           |     1           |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    1       |    Year 5    |     6           |     3           |
|------------+-+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
```

Which should be a total of 3 records

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please edit to add tags to specify the RDBMS, e.g. `sql-server` and maybe the specific version, e.g. `sql-server-2016`. Also, maybe I'm missing something, but the desired output looks exactly the same as the result you said you got above ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't quite clear - there are 2, not 3, rows with parentid = 3 and year = 'Year 5'.

So, you may want to use an `INNER JOIN`, if you only want records that have entries in `T2`:

```
SELECT eletter_id, eletter_form, status_letterid, status_parentid
FROM dbo.eletter T1
INNER JOIN dbo.status T2 ON T2.status_letterid = T1.eletter_id;
```

Or perhaps you meant that the query should give you specific parentid and year values, in which case you may want to specify those in a `WHERE` clause in the query:

```
SELECT eletter_id, eletter_form, status_letterid, status_parentid
FROM dbo.eletter T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.status T2 ON T2.status_letterid = T1.eletter_id
WHERE T1.eletter_form = 'Year 5' AND T2.status_parentid = 3;
```

Comment: hi there how do i select the answer? just reading the doos and donts. Apologies for not doing it right, dont want to offend anybody

Comment: @VitorFernandes-Neto Looks like you figured it out - glad it was helpful, and welcome to DBA.SE!